# Determine a basis for $x^T A x = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a symmetric matrix. I would like to determine a basis for the following set
$$\mathcal{X} = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n \ | \ x^{\top} A x = 0 \}.$$
I tried to separate this subspace into two subspaces such that $\mathcal{X} = \mathcal{X}_1 \cup \mathcal{X}_2$ where $\mathcal{X}_1 = \mathrm{Ker}(A)$ and
$$\mathcal{X}_2 = \{ x\in \mathbb{R}^n \ | \ A x \in \mathrm{Ker}(x^{\top}), \ x \ne 0\}.$$
It is easy to find a basis for $\mathcal{X}_1$ but how can I compute a basis for $\mathcal{X}_2$ (or directly for $\mathcal{X}$)?

Comment: In general $\chi$ is not a vector space because it may fail to be an additive sub group.

Comment: You are absolutely right, thanks for pointing that out. However, if A is positive semi-definite, would it be possible then?

Comment: For $\mathcal{X}$ to be a linear subspace, you'll need $x^T Ay + y^T Ax = 0$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ (do you see why?). This is the same as saying that $A$ needs to be antisymmetric. But if $A$ is antisymmetric, you can check that $\mathcal{X} = \mathbb{R}^n$, which is perhaps not very interesting.

Comment: @spin In the semi-definite case $\mathcal{X} = \ker(A)$.

Comment: @DanielArreola something I hadn't thought about before. Combined with my comment this says the only semi-definite, anti-symmetric matrix is $0$.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins You just need $x^\top A y + y^\top A x = 0$ for all $x,y \in \mathcal{X}$, not $\Bbb{R}^n$. As Daniel says, any semi-definite matrix will work, not just the $0$ matrix.

Comment: @TheoBendit Ah you're right. It just needs to be antisymmetric on $\mathcal{X}$.